# Very very VERY! Weird Windows 7 bug with network connection shut down

Tags: internet, connection

this is the first time after almost a year now since i have this issue. I newer asked for help before because A- i could live with this, but its very annoying, B- i have no time to write this long post. i try be as much specific about problem as possible.

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 x64.
Hardware platform: Laptop.

In short term: NETWORK CONNECTION LOSES INTERNET AFTER A WHILE (this is 100% windows, not modem fault
more details: **After i turn on computer, i can use internet easily, all works fine. until 3~5hours passes and suddenly i notice that somethings wrong, the internet is like still here not functioning as it should be, for example: facebook - if there is more then one tab open about facebook, one tab loses connection to chat messages and stays offline, meanwhile the second tad can still perfectly receive messages in fb chat from friends. BUT, if i hit SHIFT+F5 in result to refresh page clearly and see whats going on, all i get is just few pictures of facebook and other whats left wont load, its lost, chat wont work anymore. if i hit SHIFT F5 again, it wont load nothing at all now. It seems like internet browser (firefox in this case) loses some kind of authentication little by little to be able to receive data.
But this not stops here. This happens to every single app on PC at that point of time. no matter its chrome or skype, thay all start to lose data little by little.

Strange thing gets even more: if at that time i am connected my android device in development usb debugging mode to laptop, developer console "eclipse" loses connection to my android device. at very same time as internet is gone. However, none of other USB devices who are connected in standard mode, as usb flash, keyboard, mouse, etc, they still function perfectly.

Problem appeared probably after one harsh laptop shut down, when you hold the power button to kill all processes and turn it on again. usually this wont affect pc, but.. sometimes it will, especially if that that very second some registry code was started to be written for specific service and there was no backup..

At first days after internet connection problem persisted i tryed system restore, it dint helped. Then i used simply so keep restart pc and use it again till internet stops after 3~5 hours. This got annoying and i started to used how i could fix it. I thought i found a solution but seems like its just temporary one just to win few hours more of internet.
What i found is - i have to go in services app, and STOP "Internet Connection Sharing ICS"
this will make internet work again for about 20minutes, then i can go back to services and START same service and STOP it again. This gives extra 1-2hours of internet. Also my USB debugging device starts to function to!! its weird huh, cause all i do is killing INTERNET sharing service.
After internet is gone third time - nothing helps, i can restart what service i want, nothing. no page will load, i have to restart my PC.
**

ok.. just to be clear here:

SYMPTOMS:

> @INTERNET STARTS TO LOSE PACKETS OR SOMETHING AFTER FEW HOURS OF USE
>
> @INTERNET CONNECTION ICON IN NOTIFICATION PANEL ALWAYS SHOWS RED X,
>    FROM PC BOOT-UP AS IF THERE NEWER WAS INTERNET CONNECTION, HOWEVER IF
>    YOU PRESS ON IT, IT SHOWS CONNECTED NETWORKS IN LIST
>
> @NETWORK AND SHARING CENTER >> CHANGE ADAPTER SETTINGS: SHOWS NOTHING IN THERE,
>    LIKE THERE IS NO NETWORK DEVICES INSTALLED. THIS ISSUE HAPPENS NO
>    MATTER IF I CONNECTED ON LAN OR WI-FI OR 4G NETWORK USB DONGLE

Things i try'd:

> REINSTALLING NETWORK DEVICES DRIVERS
>
> STOPPING AND STARTING NETWORK CONNECTION SHARING SERVICE AND MANY
>   OTHER SERVICES
>
> REMOVING LAPTOP BATTERY
>
> RUNNING WINDOWS NETWORK TROUBLESHOOTER
>
> also this: 
>   processes running the NlaSvc and Netprofm services (using ProcMon), and noticed that both were denied read/write access to subkeys within the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList hierarchy.
>   The processes were running as NetworkService and LocalService, respectively, so I tried adding full access for these service accounts to the entire subkey mentioned above.
>   dint helped..
>
> also this: Network Location Awareness setting up as automatic startup (was set same as default) dint helped.

Now i am out of options. this is really not an easy to solve. 
and please dont give me ideas of reinstalling windows, this is not a solution!!
because i am a graphics designer and my windows have lots of lots custom setting made apps, it would take me ages to set everything up as it is now.

thank you.

Comment: Sometimes it is not worth it trying to diagnose these kind of errors, especially not if it just involves one person who forcefully shut down the computer in a way that Windows does not like. Even if you manage to find what is causing the internet do disappear, you can't be sure it didn't affect anything else that will come back and bite you in the future... I'd just suggest reinstalling and just forget about the whole thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would normally post this as a comment due to the number of questions I am going to need answers to, but I will also give a few suggestions for possible fixes.

1. Is this a wired or wireless internet connection?
2. What model/make laptop are you using?
3. What make/model of NIC (wired or wireless) does this laptop have?
4. Have you tried to change any of the DNS settings for the NIC in question?
5. What type of network (work, home, public) are you using?
6. You mention facebook is having issues if you leave it idle in Firefox.   What about IE?  Chrome?   Have you tried other browsers?
7. In your post, you seem to use the term PC (which to me means a Desktop usually) quite often, but at the top of the post you say that this issue is happening on a laptop.   I just want to be sure we are talking about the same computer and same issue.
8. Have you tried to switch out ethernet cables to eliminate a bad cable as the source of the issue?   I have seen cables that were professionally made fail many times in my career.
9. Why do you have ICS enabled?  Do you have some specific reason to use ICS?   I have seen ICS cause issues with connectivity before and I would recommend turning it off if you do not need it for some specific reason.

Here are my suggestions:

- Switch out ethernet cables to eliminate that as the source of the issue.
- Go into the adapter settings and change your DNS server settings to use 4.2.2.3 and 4.2.2.7 - your issue seems like it could be DNS related based on the fact that the adapter status in the taskbar willl show a red X if it cannot properly resolve hostname.   I know my ISP (comcast) has regular issues with their DNS server and the end result is all of the computers at my house will show that they are not connected to the internet, when in reality it is DNS that is having issues not the entire internet.
- Change your network type to Work if it is not already set that way.   Stay away from Public and Home.
- If you are in a windows homegroup, leave the homegroup and join a workgroup instead.   Homegroups in Windows = Networking Issues.
- Go and buy a USB to Ethernet adapter.   This should eliminate any issues with the onboard NICs that you are having.   Here is a link to tigerdirect for a $10 USB to Ethernet Adapter that works with Windows 7. http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=4776334&CatId=589

Obviously this is not ideal, but if you have a USB to Ethernet adapter connected and you still have the same issues as you did with the onboard adapters, that probabally means there is something wrong with the computer itself and you are going to have to reinstall windows, and hope that fixes it.  If you somehow fried/damaged the USB or Ethernet Controller by shutting down the computer improperly, your laptop is hosed and you may need to buy another one - but the likleyhood of that being the issue is very low and hopefully the USB to Ethernet adapter should do the trick.